# Alphabetized Around: an Around-the-Bend

Tags: logical-deduction, crosswords

This is a variety crossword type called Around-the-Bend

### Rules

- Each word goes from left to right on its numbered line, and then continues from right to left on the next line
- #20 wraps back around to #1

Example: If #1 was "TRAPS", then #2 must start with "SP" and #20 must end with "ART". #1 would be entered as TRA in the #1 row and SP in the #2 row, so if you read #1 left-to-right and then #2 right-to-left it spells "TRAPS"

[image: grid]

Length of each row: 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 3.

(I've included #1's cells again at the bottom to make the wrapping-around clearer)

**Clues:**

Bible (3 wrds.)
Car wash worker, perhaps
Dirty
Large flat fish
Mentioned
One out of 100 Americans
Online greeting
Part used for nudging
Person who slows everyone down
Samson's downfall
Sandy tracts, in England
Sighting
Soldier, slangily
Spun around
Squashed circle
Toad-losing wizard
Transported by car
Trustworthy
Wilson's middle name
Woman seen by her people as a "Moses"

... what?? No numbers? Well, yes, someone - I blame the Cryptic Cat - alphabetized all of my clues. You'll have to figure out where the words fit into the grid yourself! I've left the numbers in the grid for reference purposes, and to demonstrate how #20 wraps around onto #1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In grid order:

> ```
>  1 |     N A M   Named
>  2 |       D E   Denes
>  3 |     S E N   Senator
>  4 |   R O T A   Rotated
>  5 |     D E T   Detailer
>  6 | R E L I A   Reliable
>  7 |     E L B   Elbow
>  8 |       W O   Woodrow
>  9 | W O R D O   Word of God
> 10 |   D O G F   Dogface
> 11 |     E C A   E-card
> 12 |       D R   Driven
> 13 |   N E V I   Neville
> 14 |     E L L   Ellipse
> 15 |   E S P I   Espial
> 16 |       L A   Laggard
> 17 | D R A G G   Draggled
> 18 |     D E L   Delilah
> 19 |   H A L I   Halibut
> 20 |     T U B   Tubman
>  1 |     N A M
> ```

In clue order:

> ```
>  9 | Bible (3 wrds.) -> WORD OF GOD
>  5 | Car wash worker, perhaps -> DETAILER
> 17 | Dirty -> DRAGGLED
> 19 | Large flat fish -> HALIBUT
>  1 | Mentioned -> NAMED
>  3 | One out of 100 Americans -> SENATOR
> 11 | Online greeting -> E-CARD
>  7 | Part used for nudging -> ELBOW
> 16 | Person who slows everyone down -> LAGGARD
> 18 | Samson's downfall -> DELILAH
>  2 | Sandy tracts, in England -> DENES
> 15 | Sighting -> ESPIAL
> 10 | Soldier, slangliy -> DOGFACE
>  5 | Spun around -> ROTATED
> 14 | Squashed circle -> ELLIPSE
> 13 | Toad-losing wizard -> NEVILLE
> 12 | Transported by car -> DRIVEN
>  6 | Trustworthy -> RELIABLE
>  8 | Wilson's middle name -> WOODROW
> 20 | Woman seen by her people as a "Moses" -> TUBMAN
> ```

Confession:

> I needed Qat to find LAGGARD/DRAGGLED.

Comment: Your R and D for 'driven' are the wrong way round I think, well done on getting the answer! I'd only just started filling in the grid :)

Comment: Oh, and 'ggard' is the wrong way round too I think

Comment: I'll give you the check once you fix the wrong-way-round letters.

Comment: Ugh, I have no brain. Will fix.

Comment: OK, should be right now. Sorry about that.

Comment: *cough*... BUT/TUB as well, I think...!

Comment: No brain. No brain _at all_. Fixed. Thank you.